# vim: quick column insert

Tags: vim

I have been using Vim for my text editor in place the notepad++. I want to know is there a way to perform "quick column insert" in vim.

As I know, we are able to perform column insert in vim in following steps:

1. move to the position
2. enter column visual mode          <kbd>CTRL+v</kbd>
3. select the column                 <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>k</kbd>
4. enter into column insert mode     <kbd>shift+i</kbd>
5. insert the text
6. type <kbd>Esc</kbd>

then the column insertion is performed

is there a way to delete the step 4 and perform column insertion directly?

Comment: You want the kind of real-time feedback you get in ST2, don't you?

Comment: So... Skip step 4... What happens if the first character you want to type is j or k?

Comment: Just found out about column insertion mode! Simply `shift+i`! Fandabidozi. Of course you need a step to establish a new mode, because without it you're still in the original mode. And the modes are the most powerful feature of Vim. No other editor on the planet does it like Vim.

Answer (score 4):

I use the following mappings that allow to prepend / append spaces (also multiple with a `[count]` before the mapping):

```
:vnoremap <C-Space> I<Space><Esc>gv
:vnoremap <C-S-Space> A<Space><Esc>gv
```

Custom mappings such as these are the key to efficient editing, and very powerful in Vim. You'll find all the details in the `:help`.